# How to connect HTML and CSS and check in browser

Tags: html, css

I run the below code in a browser using vs code.
It does not work.
I've just started learning HTML today.
I've tried to connect CSS to HTML.

The below code was still working before add  in head HTML.

Can you help me out, please?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewprt" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body background="background.jpeg">
    <!--Navbar start-->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top shadow-sm navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light py-3 py-lg-0 px-lg-5">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand ml-lg-3">
            <h1 class="m-0 display-5"><span class="text-primary">Free</span>Folio</h1>
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse px-lg-3" id="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav m-auto py-0">
                <a href="#home" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                <a href="#about" class="nav-item nav-link active">About</a>
            </div>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-menu d-none d-lg-block" stype="background-colour:#457efa; colour: #ffffff;"></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Navbar End-->
</body>

</html>
```

index.css

```css
/* Navigation Menu*/

.navbar-light {
    display: none;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding: 25px 10px;
    color: #343a40;
    font-weight: 500;
    outline: none;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
    color: #0BCEAF;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: is your index.css in the same folder of index.html? You can check in browser console if you have some errors

Comment: @Sfili_81 Bro see carefully... `navbar-light` have the `display: none` and it's included in `<nav>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you have added `navbar-light` in the top nav tag and in the CSS its property is defined as `display:none;`. So when you have set `display:none;` property on the parent nav tag then you can not see anything.

Now another thing is that from your code I can see that the classes you have used are based on the `Bootstrap`. So to see this code in action you have to include `Bootstrap` in your project too. Copy the below cdn link to see code in action

```html
<!--CSS Only-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewprt" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio Website</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body background="background.jpeg">
    <!--Navbar start-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <h1 class="m-0 display-5"><span class="text-primary">Free</span>Folio</h1>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Navbar End-->

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can read more about bootstrap and its docs here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine. I checked it in my local machine. In your `index.css` file you have written `.navbar-light{display: none;}`. That's why nothing is visible in the page. It also shows your `index.css` file is working.